# I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong that my hover isn't working on my website

Tags: html, css

On my website: [HQ](https://www.gx0st.com/home.html)

There seems to be an issue where if you try to hover over the top section, under where it says files, you will not be able to **hover** over the image to go to the link. BUT, if you try on the bottom section of the videos you are able too. What did I do wrong? I am currently looking for an answer. So if anyone can help, I appreciate it. I really do. I am a noob. I know. Lol.

> By the way, there's a hint (to me it's a hint) if you hover over the WORDS of the top section, you can click. So I guess that's my clue.

*Please tell me what I can do to make my question helpful to anyone, I am new at this.*

**I tried to see if I misspelled or missed something in my HTML, I am moving on to my CSS**:

```
/* Projects section */

.projects-section {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10rem 2rem;
  background: black;
}

.projects-section-header {
  max-width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto 6rem auto;
  border-bottom: 0.2rem solid black;
}

@media (max-width: 28.75em) {
  .projects-section-header {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }
}

/* "Automagic" image grid using no media queries */
.projects-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 4rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
}

@media (max-width: 30.625em) {
  .projects-section {
    padding: 6rem 1rem;
  }

  .projects-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}

.project {
  background: black;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 13px;
}

.code {
  color: var(--main-white);
  transition: color 0.3s ease-out;
}

.project.code:hover {
  color: #00ff22;
}

.project-image {
  height: calc(100% - 6.8rem);
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.project-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem 0.5rem;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.btn-show-all {
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: black;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-out;
}

.btn-show-all:hover {
  background: red;;
}

.btn-show-all:hover > i {
  transform: translateX(2px);
}

.btn-show-all > i {
  margin-left: 10px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Main thing to help is add some html and css. Anything that will point *us* in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your video container is overlapping your links.  Add this to your CSS

```
    .video-container {
    height: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.example {
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
background: #DDD;
}
.example:hover {
width: 88%;
height: 300px;
background: grey;
transform: translated(10px);
}
</style>
<div class="example">
<p> Just put your mouser here and watch it change! </p>
</div>
```

It is simple, you just need the `:hover` bit!

Comment: thank you so much  for the help <3 I will pass it on one day

Comment: @GhostRobles No problem at all\

Answer (score 1):

The `.video-container` height is partially overlapping the `#welcome-section`. This problem could be fix it in many ways.

For example, you can adjust the `.video-container` height or just simply add `pointer-events: none;` to the `.video-container` class if you don't want to click on it.